# How to specify custom behavior on line breaking

Tags: line-breaking

Is it possible to detect when LaTeX breaks a long line of text and add some custom behavior to it?

Specifically, If a long sentence breaks, I want to prepend some code to all but the first line, similar to what the `listings` package provides with `postbreak`.

I tried hinting where LaTeX should break using `discretionary` and it works in some cases, but not when I try to prepend the lines with horizontal whitespace. What are the alternatives?

Comment: your question isn't very clear, adding arbitrary material is not really possible unless you take over the line breaking completely  but the white space to the left and right of each line is controllable by the paragraph parameters, or the `\parshape` primitive, or more usually in latex by use of a `list` environment

Comment: `\parshape` looks like the way to go when you want to indent broken lines. I can then add some (non-space) characters using discretionary as I mentioned. This fits my current needs.

Comment: Using a custom `list` environment might even be better. But then my problem is that multiple _items_ are allowed on the same line. Only when the line is full, I want the `\item` commands to include some extra code.